# How to install Office 2010 in Windows 8?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

How to install Office 2010 in Windows 8? When I installed 8,my installed Office from 7 didn't come over.

Comment: Do you have disc of Office-2010? If yes then just run it and install it, or setup will ask you to repair the existing files if it find already installation of Office.

Answer (score 3):

You install it in precisely the same way as you did before on win 7.

- If you have it on an optical disc, install from disc.
- If you started the installer from the network, use that way again.
- If it came pre-installed as a trail version and you bought a legal key, use the installation files you downloaded from the place where you bought the key.
- If it came pre-installed as a trail version and you bought a legal key and did not download anything: Search your [electronic] paperwork to see what your key is, and download the files.